# pass localstorage value from html page to embed website

Tags: html, reactjs

i have  react website embedded inside html page using embed tag. My react website needs a value stored in a local storage of html page.How can i make it possible?

Comment: Can you show us the code you've already tried?

Comment: @Mac i dont have any idea on this . I searched for it in internet but no luck